# SIMPLE string implementation in c++

Tags: c++, string

I started writing a very simple implementation of a string class in c++, here is the code:

```
class String
{
public:
    String()
    {
        this->_length = 0;
        this->_size = 0;
        this->_string = NULL;
    }
    String(const char* str)
    {
        this->_length = strlen(str);
        this->_size = this->_length + 1;
        this->_string = new char[this->_size];

        strcpy_s(this->_string, this->_size, str);
    }
    ~String()
    {
        if (this->_string != NULL)
        {
            delete[] this->_string;
            this->_string = NULL;
        }
    }

    String& operator+(const char* str)
    {
        String* temp = new String();

        temp->_length = strlen(str) + strlen(this->_string);
        temp->_size = temp->_length + 1;
        temp->_string = new char[temp->_size];

        strcpy_s(temp->_string, temp->_size, this->_string);
        strcat_s(temp->_string, temp->_size, str);

        return (String&)*temp;
    }

    int Length()
    {
        return this->_length;
    }

private:
    int _size;
    int _length;
    char* _string;
};
```

You can see that my implementation of operator+ is absolutely wrong, in fact there is a memory leak.
Writing the operator+= is way simpler because I can simply concatenate the char* with this->_string and return *this.
I need help with the operator+ implementation.

Note: This is homework so I don't want the solution the copy-paste but it would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction...

Thanks

Edit:
I added the copy constructor:

```
String(const String& str)
{
    this->_length = str._length;
    this->_size = str._size;
    this->_string = new char[this->_size];
    strcpy_s(this->_string, this->_size, str._string);
}
```

the operator= and the operator+=:

```
String& operator=(const String& str)
{
    if (this != &str)
    {
        this->_length = str._length;
        this->_size = str._size;
        this->_string = new char[this->_size];

        strcpy_s(this->_string, this->_size, str._string);
    }

    return *this;
}
String& operator+=(const String& str)
{
    this->_length = this->_length + str._length;
    this->_size = this->_length + 1;

    char* buffer = new char[this->_size];
    strcpy_s(buffer, this->_size, this->_string);
    strcat_s(buffer, this->_size, str._string);

    delete[] this->_string;
    this->_string = buffer;

    return *this;
}
```

but there is still something wrong because if I run a while(true) loop like this:

```
while (true)
{
    String a = String("string a");
    String b = a;
    b = "string b";
    b += " string c";
}
```

the memory used by the process will increase continuously

Comment: `temp` doesn't need to be a pointer. Make it an automatic variable. You also should **not** return by reference in that case.

Comment: @0x499602D2 shouldn't you make that an answer?

Comment: @Named There are also other problems.

Comment: Pls look at this - http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/410105/overloading-operator-to-concat-string

Comment: If `operator+=` is simpler to write, write it, then define `operator+(const char* other)` as `return String(*this) += other;`.

Comment: Also need to follow "rule of three".

Comment: Writing operator += isn't that much simpler.  You can't just concatenate the new string with the old.  You have to reallocate the old string to have a large enough size to accommodate the result.

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't just write #include <string>?

Comment: @DanielDaranas he said it was for homework...

Comment: @AK4749 Oops! I hadn't noticed that bit.

Answer (score 6):

You could reuse the `operator+=` in the `operator+`:

(The code below assumes that you have an `operator+=`, a copy constructor and an assignment operator which is NOT the case in the code you pasted).

EDIT: As suggested by Jerry Coffin the following operator should NOT be a class member but a free operator:

EDIT2: And to allow the compiler a bit more optimizations the first argument is not a const-reference anymore:

```
String operator+(String a, String const &b) {
  a += b;
  return a;
}
```

By this you can have a more simple `operator+=` and simply copy constructor and build the complex thing on the simple ones.

And do not forget:

You MUST implement a copy constructor and assignment operator. Otherwise the compiler generates it for you in a wrong way: The compiler generates code that simply copies the content. So it also copies the pointer but does not allocate new memory for the copy. Then you have two instances referencing the same memory and both try to deallocate it in the destructor which is undefined behavior.

Comment: but he still need copy constructor and assignment operator

Comment: @Sergi0: Yes, he needs...but he needs in any way since otherwise his implementation is wrong (i.e. it would use the automatic assignment operator and copy constructor that just copies the pointer which leads to double de-allocation).

Comment: and strlen isn't safe to use without checking for NULL

Comment: @Sergi0: I do not want to evaluate the remaining code pasted in the original question but only try to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to implement your `operator+` is in terms of `+=`. Create a copy of the left operand, then use `+=` to add the right operand to it, and finally return the result.

Also note that `operator+` shouldn't usually be a member function -- it should normally be a free function. The basic difference is that as a member function, the left operand must already be a string for it to work. As a free function, your string constructor can be used to convert (for example) a string literal. For example, `string+"something";` will work with a member function, but `"something" + string;` won't. With `+` overloaded as a free function, both of them will work.